# Is this possible to call c/c++ application from DB2 stored procedure/trigger?

Tags: c++, c, db2

Is this possible to call c/c++ application from DB2 stored procedure/trigger? If yes, what would be general steps doing it? Any pointers to web resources on the subject?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

A quick google search turned up [this promising result](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9/topic/com.ibm.db2.udb.apdv.sql.doc/doc/c0009701.htm).

Comment: Thanks pmg, looks like external routine is a way to go, at least this is what I'm going to try first.